# Magento exception log issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i need a help.

My magento's exception.log is getting a error that I have no idea how to solve, and why this is happening, take a look at the error below:

```
2016-06-10T17:46:42+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Dynamicslideshow_Block_List' in /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:

#0 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('dynamicslidesho...', Array)
#2 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('dynamicslidesho...', 'dynamicslidesho...')
#3 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('dynamicslidesho...', 'dynamicslidesho...')
#4 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/controllers/CategoryController.php(48): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Sm_Shopby_CategoryController->viewAction()
#10 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Controller/Router.php(96): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#11 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Sm_Shopby_Controller_Router->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /chroot/home/reperfum/mydomain.com.br/html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

someone can help me to solve that?

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your layout XML files is referencing a block with the type `dynamicslideshow/list`. This block alias is failing to resolve to a class correctly, which could be caused by a variety of reasons, but the most likely reason is that you've deleted a module out of `app/code/local` and forgotten to remote a reference to it from `app/design`.

Search in `app/design` for XML files containing `type="dynamicslideshow/list`
 and for now delete the references to it. If you want to keep the module in question you'll need to share more information about how you've implemented it.

Comment: There also could be an error in the module config.xml file.

Comment: @Zefiryn how do you figure that? I'm saying layout due to the fact that the last trace of local code in the stack is coming from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()`

Comment: You are correct, somewhere in the layout (or cms block/page) is a reference to `dynamicslideshow/list` block. Magento tries to convert block group `dynamicslideshow` into a class prefix. If there is no configuration for such name it will assume this is a magento module and return `Mage_Dynamicslideshow_Block` as a class prefix making `dynamicslideshow/list` resolve to `Mage_Dynamicslideshow_Block_List`  (as shown in the exception message) which does not exists.